# cleveref not supporting a language

Tags: languages, cleveref

I want a document where you can select between two languages and use cleveref. However, cleveref does *not* support the second language `nynorsk`. I still want to be able to use the english version, so I can not simply use `\crefname` to redefine the names. Here is an example (note that cref is provided in english):

```
\documentclass[5p,a4paper]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english,nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english,nynorsk]{cleveref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{nynorsk} % Switch between english and nynorsk

\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2 \label{eq:E=mc}
\end{equation}

\Cref{eq:E=mc}

\appendix

\section{A} % To check that current language option is working.

\end{document}
```

My question is: **How can I define the cref names for the language** `nynorsk` **whilst still being able to use the english versions?**

I was thinking of maybe using if statements to check if the selected language is `nynorsk`and if it is, use the appropriate names.
I also am considering to send an email to the maintainer of the `cleveref` package with the appropriate code for the `.sty` file to include this language (as a long term solution).

Comment: Well, you'll have to make yourself the nynorsk translations, probably via `cleveref.cfg`.

Comment: It is the same as your last question, this time you can add the corresponding settings to `\extrasnynorsk`. And by the way, I think that the most difficult part is not about the names for these special environments/commands, but rather those commands `\crefpairconjunction`, `\crefmiddleconjunction`, `\creflastconjunction`, etc. which need to be carefully selected. You can see the preset definitions in `cleveref.dtx`, and define you own version, for example in `cleveref.cfg` as Bernard stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do almost no language checking yourself, if you use `cleveref`'s interface to define language-specific definitions. This interface is internal and not documented, so things could theoretically break in future versions, so I only recommend this for testing and the short term. A medium- to long-term solution would be to contact the maintainer and ask him to include language support for `nynorsk` directly in the package.

For the example I just copied the language definitions from `norsk` to `nynorsk`, so you will have to translate the terms yourself.

```
\documentclass[5p,a4paper,nynorsk,english]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
\cref@addlanguagedefs{nynorsk}{%
  \PackageInfo{cleveref}{loaded `nynorsk' language definitions}%
  \renewcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ til\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand\crefrangepreconjunction{}%
  \renewcommand\crefrangepostconjunction{}%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ og\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{, }%
  \renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ og\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction}{ og\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\crefmiddlegroupconjunction}{, }%
  \renewcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ og\nobreakspace}%
 %
  \Crefname{equation}{Likning}{Likningene}%
  \Crefname{figure}{Figur}{Figurene}%
  \Crefname{subfigure}{Figur}{Figurene}%
  \Crefname{table}{Tabell}{Tabellene}%
  \Crefname{subtable}{Tabell}{Tabellene}%
  \Crefname{page}{Side}{Siden}%
  \Crefname{part}{Del}{Delene}%
  \Crefname{chapter}{Kapittel}{Kapitlene}%
  \Crefname{section}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
  \Crefname{subsection}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
  \Crefname{subsubsection}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
  \Crefname{appendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
  \Crefname{subappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
  \Crefname{subsubappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
  \Crefname{subsubsubappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
  \Crefname{enumi}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
  \Crefname{enumii}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
  \Crefname{enumiii}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
  \Crefname{enumiv}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
  \Crefname{enumv}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
  \Crefname{footnote}{Fotnote}{Fotnotene}%
  \Crefname{theorem}{Teorem}{Teoremene}%
  \Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemma}%
  \Crefname{corollary}{Korollar}{Korollarene}%
  \Crefname{proposition}{P\aa stand}{P\aa standene}%
  \Crefname{definition}{Definisjon}{Definisjonene}%
  \Crefname{result}{Resultat}{Resultatene}%
  \Crefname{example}{Eksempel}{Eksemplene}%
  \Crefname{remark}{Bemerkning}{Bemerkningene}%
  \Crefname{note}{Note}{Notene}%
  \Crefname{algorithm}{Algoritme}{Algoritmene}%
  \Crefname{listing}{Opplisting}{Opplistingene}%
  \Crefname{line}{Linje}{Linjene}%
 %
  \if@cref@capitalise%
    \crefname{equation}{Likning}{Likningene}%
    \crefname{figure}{Figur}{Figurene}%
    \crefname{subfigure}{Figur}{Figurene}%
    \crefname{table}{Tabell}{Tabellene}%
    \crefname{subtable}{Tabell}{Tabellene}%
    \crefname{page}{Side}{Siden}%
    \crefname{part}{Del}{Delene}%
    \crefname{chapter}{Kapittel}{Kapitlene}%
    \crefname{section}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
    \crefname{subsection}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
    \crefname{subsubsection}{Avsnitt}{Avsnittene}%
    \crefname{appendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subsubappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subsubsubappendix}{Tillegg}{Tilleggene}%
    \crefname{enumi}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
    \crefname{enumii}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
    \crefname{enumiii}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
    \crefname{enumiv}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
    \crefname{enumv}{Punkt}{Punktene}%
    \crefname{footnote}{Fotnote}{Fotnotene}%
    \crefname{theorem}{Teorem}{Teoremene}%
    \crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemma}%
    \crefname{corollary}{Korollar}{Korollarene}%
    \crefname{proposition}{P\aa stand}{P\aa standene}%
    \crefname{definition}{Definisjon}{Definisjonene}%
    \crefname{result}{Resultat}{Resultatene}%
    \crefname{example}{Eksempel}{Eksemplene}%
    \crefname{remark}{Bemerkning}{Bemerkningene}%
    \crefname{note}{Note}{Notene}%
    \crefname{algorithm}{Algoritme}{Algoritmene}%
    \crefname{listing}{Opplisting}{Opplistingene}%
    \crefname{line}{Linje}{Linjene}%
 %
  \else%
    \crefname{equation}{likning}{likningene}%
    \crefname{figure}{figur}{figurene}%
    \crefname{subfigure}{figur}{figurene}%
    \crefname{table}{tabell}{tabellene}%
    \crefname{subtable}{tabell}{tabellene}%
    \crefname{page}{side}{siden}%
    \crefname{part}{del}{delene}%
    \crefname{chapter}{kapittel}{kapitlene}%
    \crefname{section}{avsnitt}{avsnittene}%
    \crefname{subsection}{avsnitt}{avsnittene}%
    \crefname{subsubsection}{avsnitt}{avsnittene}%
    \crefname{appendix}{tillegg}{tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subappendix}{tillegg}{tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subsubappendix}{tillegg}{tilleggene}%
    \crefname{subsubsubappendix}{tillegg}{tilleggene}%
    \crefname{enumi}{punkt}{punktene}%
    \crefname{enumii}{punkt}{punktene}%
    \crefname{enumiii}{punkt}{punktene}%
    \crefname{enumiv}{punkt}{punktene}%
    \crefname{enumv}{punkt}{punktene}%
    \crefname{footnote}{fotnote}{fotnotene}%
    \crefname{theorem}{teorem}{teoremene}%
    \crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemma}%
    \crefname{corollary}{korollar}{korollarene}%
    \crefname{proposition}{p\aa stand}{p\aa standene}%
    \crefname{definition}{definisjon}{definisjonene}%
    \crefname{result}{resultat}{resultatene}%
    \crefname{example}{eksempel}{eksemplene}%
    \crefname{remark}{bemerkning}{bemerkningene}%
    \crefname{note}{note}{notene}%
    \crefname{algorithm}{algoritme}{algoritmene}%
    \crefname{listing}{opplisting}{opplistingene}%
    \crefname{line}{linje}{linjene}%
  \fi}% end \cref@loadlanguagedefs
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Cref{eq:E=mc}

\selectlanguage{nynorsk} % Switch between english and nynorsk

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eq:E=mc}
\end{equation}

\Cref{eq:E=mc}

\appendix

\section{A} % To check that current language option is working.


\end{document}
```

[image: Likning (1)]

**There is one caveat**. Due to the implementation of the language options our new language will not work correctly if it is the document main language. In that case it helps to explicitly switch the language to the main language directly after `\begin{document}`. This is just a small hitch that won't be relevant once `cleveref` supports your language out of the box, though.